# Creating a game with rectangular shapes

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, game, inheritance

I'm using Pygame to create a small game with few rectangle shapes.  However, I want to learn more about classes, and I'm trying to use them.  I'm very new to classes and inheritance, but I want to learn the best habits possible. I'm using Python 3.3.2.

```
import pygame

class Screen(object):
    ''' Creates main window and handles surface object. '''
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.WIDTH = width
        self.HEIGHT = height
        self.SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT), 0, 32)

class GameManager(object):
    ''' Handles game state datas and updates. '''
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

pygame.init()
Window = Screen(800, 500)
Game = GameManager(Window)
```

I skipped a few functions to make it simpler.  The thing that bothers me is that I've been told that I don't need `GameManager` to be subclasses of `Screen`.  I was advised to use this implementation, but I find it very strange to use 'Window' as a parameter to `GameManager`.

Do I need to use inheritance?  Should I use `super()`?  Later on, I will have class `Player` and I will need some of the attributes from the `Screen` class.  From the viewpoint of designing OO for a GUI game using Pygame.

Comment: See [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/222914)

Answer (score 3):

First off, you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object` when creating classes. In Python 3.x, you can just type `class MyClass:`, and leave it as that if you aren't inheriting from any other classes.

Secondly, I think your current design is fine, as long as the `Screen` class implements more methods, and the `GameManager` as well.

Finally, just a little nitpicky tip, your variables `Window`, and `Game` should be renamed to `window` and `game`.
Likewise, in `Screen`, the attributes `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT`, `SURFACE` should be renamed to `width`, `height`, `surface`, respectively.
Actually more than being nitpicky,
these recommendations come from [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide.